# how to write a simple audio player on android?

Tags: android

I have written a simple audio player on android(below). And trying to run on virtual device(AVD). But I am not getting the sound. Is it not possible to get sound using AVD ?
Kindly help me..
Thanks

```
package com.example.helloplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloPlayer extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource("/home/usr/audio/file.mp3");
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Please your mp3 file put in your app Raw folder and then used below code

```
mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Hi, raw folder means in /res or in /helloplayer folder ? I have created a folder /helloplayer/res/audio and put file.mp3 there. Is it fine if i use    mp.setDataSource(R.audio.file.mpe);

Comment: @Gpathy   /res/raw/file.mp3  then mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file); access.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the mp3 file as a resource to your app. You can't access files on the device like that.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set data source from devices internal or external memory. I think you set datasource path of your computer.

Please check this [link](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-mediaplayer-example).

Answer (score 1):

Does the file exist on the internal or external memory of the virtual device?
It looks like you're using a path on your computer.

See [Using the External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) on how to do this. [Here is a tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/create-sd-card-in-android-emulator-and.html) on how to create an Emulator with external storage and how to copy a file onto the external storage.